# Does curl restarts the timeout clock in case of redirect?

Tags: curl, timeout, libcurl

We are using the libcurl C library and the code set the curl timeout to 30ms and follow redirect

```
CURLOPT_NOSIGNAL=1
CURLOPT_TIMEOUT_MS=30ms
CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION=1
CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS=2
```

When the request success or fail the curl returns within 50ms or times out exactly after 50ms. But when the request hits the redirect it follows and times out ~58ms, which is more than 50ms.

Comment: First, curl doesn't guarantee millisecond accuracy, and no, it doesn't restart the timeout timer. There might've been bugs in older versions regarding this.

Comment: It does not work in 7.33 version.

Comment: 7.33.0 is what I consider an example of "an older version" ...